# R: change to the same character as the previous character in a string

Tags: regex, r, char

Suppose I have a vector `c('JKA1','BP9C','SSTQ3WA')` and I want to change the character before the number to that very number, so that R returns `'JK11' 'B99C' 'SST33WA'`. Is there anyway to do this with regex or am I better off using something other than R?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Match the letter before the number and then capture the number through capturing group. Then replace the matched characters with `\\1\\1` means double times of characters present inside the group index 1.

```
> x <- c('JKA1','BP9C','SSTQ3WA')
> gsub("[A-Za-z](\\d)", "\\1\\1", x)
[1] "JK11"    "B99C"    "SST33WA"
```

`sub` function would be enough for this case.

```
> sub("[A-Z](\\d)", "\\1\\1", x)
[1] "JK11"    "B99C"    "SST33WA"
```

Comment: Another one `sub("[A-Z](?=(\\d))", "\\1", x, perl=T)`